# Prove that the line integral on $\int_\gamma z^k dz=0$ for any integer $k\neq 1$ and $\gamma: z(t)=Re^{it}$ $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Instead of evaluating it directly I have to show the following:

1) $z^k$ is a derivative of function holomorphic on $\gamma$ and

2) parametrizing $\gamma$

I think I got the first part in which all I did was integrate the $z(t)$ and its $dz$ to get an exponential function and from there we use Cauchy Riemann to show its holomorphic.  However I'm not so certain how to parametrize the gamma and use that to prove what we need to prove.

Can anybody offer some advice?